# In iOS 10, UNUserNotificationCenter's authorization status is wrong

Tags: push-notification, ios10, unusernotificationcenter

In AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I implementation the code for getting authorization status.

```
UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions = (UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound);
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (granted) {
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
}];
```

But, UNUserNotificationCenter.currentNotificationCenter().requestAuthorizationWithOptions ends always with granted  = false in the completion handler (no matter if I tap on the allow or deny button on the permission dialog) in very first time. And next times when I open my app, it returns right granted status. 
How to fix it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yes. I found that. I had called registerForeRemoteNotification method twice. After removing one, it's resolved